# PHPMailer error validation and file type validation

Tags: php, validation, phpmailer

I have tried many of the examples I have seen in SO so far and nothing works. So I am hoping someone else sees my example with a different light and solution.

I have a file upload input field that accepts only png and jpg. If it's not either then send to error page. But, here is the deal, I can't put it in a if-else conditional statement because the entire form is already in a try catch that is supposed to do the error validation. So, my question is, how do I work it in there so that it still validates if an image was input(ed) or ignore it if empty?

Here is my code in the sendmail.php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'class.smtp.php';

require_once('../recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "###########################";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // Build a page for this
     header('location: /error.php'); 
     die();

      } else {

            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                                    
            $mail->isSMTP();                                          

            try{
                $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';                              
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                           
                $mail->Port = 465;                                        
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                   
                $mail->Username = "@@@@@@@@@gmail.com";               
                $mail->Password = "#######";  

                $name = $_POST['full_name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];

                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
                $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);

                //CODE IN QUESTION
                if ($_FILES['logo']['type'] == "application/png" || $_FILES['logo']['type'] == "application/jpg") { 
                  $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['logo']['name']);
               }
                  else {
               ?>
                  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                      window.location = '/error.php';
                  </script>
               <?php
               }

               $mail->addAddress('@@@@@@@@@outlook.com', 'First Last');   

               $mail->Subject = '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@';
               $mail->MsgHTML($body);

               $mail->Send();
               $mail->ClearAddresses();
               ?>
                  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                       window.location = '/thankyou.php';
                  </script>
               <?php

          } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
          ?>
               <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                   window.location = '/error.php';
               </script>
          <?php
       } 
    }
?>
```

We can assume for the sake of simplicity the HTML is :

```
    <input type="file" name="logo"/>
```

Thank you in advance

**EDIT (ADDITION)**

Another way around it that actually does send me the file is the one below, **BUT**, it doesn't respect the validation that it should not send an unauthorized file and go to error screen. SO basically, it sends anything and everything you put in there. [Substitue for the if-else statement]

```
       $allowedExts = array("zip", "png", "jpg", "jpeg");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ((($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/png")
        || ($_FILES["logo"]["type"] == "application/jpg"))

        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            if ($_FILES["logo"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Error: " . $_FILES["logo"]["error"] ."')</script>";
        }
            else
            {
                $d='upload/';
                $de=$d . basename($_FILES['logo']['name']);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"], $de);
                $fileName = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
                $filePath = $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'];
            }
        }

        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['logo']['name']);
```

Comment: Rather than searching SO (which is by its very nature full of people doing things wrong), it's usually wise to go to the source. You're using an old version of PHPMailer, and have based your code on an old example. Aside from that, you need to separate out your problems - the issue you're asking about has nothing to do with PHPMailer.

Comment: Why are you generating javascript to do your redirects instead of doing it in PHP, like `header('Location: /thankyou.php');`? Your second example is always sending a file because your `addAttachment` call is outside all your conditions, so it will always send something.

Comment: Synchro,  I agree with everything you said,  but unfortunately,  I've had little luck with phpmailer's website.  Their examples are not built to send files from a form, instead they pass the attachments directly by location and file name. I also didn't see any of these validations there either

Comment: I agree, php instead of js makes more sense.  But I don't think this phpmailer is old at all. I downloaded it directly from their website. I see what you are saying about the addattachment outside the condition.  I'll take care of that

Comment: You're looking at the wrong place; PHPMailer lives [on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). There is no difference between sending local files and those uploaded from a form - normal [PHP upload handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) will validate and convert an uploaded file into a local file, from which point you can attach it like any other local file.

Comment: I added [an example of how to handle a file upload from a form and send it with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Comment: @Synchro That link did help me a lot. Thank you for that. It sends the file. It doesn't send it with a file type so I still have to figure that part out, but at least I'm closer to the solution. If you could post that code here as an answer so I can give you proper credit that would be great.

Comment: If you are willing to trust the uploaded filename (which isn't necessarily a good idea), just retain the supplied filename and pass it to the `addAttachment` call as the second param. PHPMailer will automatically map the filename extension to the correct MIME type.